# Docusign eSignature OAuth2.0 migration flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi

I am working on migrating Docusign basic Authentication to OAuth2.0. I followed the article [How to get access token with JWT grant authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/).

However, I am confused when trying to get the eSignature working.

Our current flow is:

We don't use a phyiscal document file, instead we use a template (templateId) that we uploaded to docusign ahead of time. Then when we make an API call, docusign returns an external url that we use to direct the user to sign the form. After the user signs the form, Docusign uses the return url that we provided to direct the user back to our application.

Any ideas which method that I should use to achieve it? With Docusign Oauth2.0 migration, we only need to update the authentication piece, we do not need to make different API calls. In other words, **We can continue to use restapi/v2 with OAuth2.0 authentication**, everything else will work as before. right?

However, I noticed that the legacy login URL still requires api_password

```
https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?include_account_id_guid=true&api_password=true&login_settings=all
```

If we do have to call restapi/v2.1 Docusign REST API along with OAuth2.0, in this article [How to request a signature using a composite template](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-composite-template-embedded/). At the end, the article shows that its expected response URL.

```
  "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1/09f2e35e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1fbc6fcf77ed?slt=eyJ0eX...i3x-4g"
```

Any inputs would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the same URL from the eSignature REST API v2.0 to make all API calls to DocuSign, except the `login_information` call in your post.
The rest of your scenario - using a template, redirecting the user etc. - can be done just the same with your access token obtained using OAuth 2.0

To get the user's information with OAuth you use the `getUserInfo()` call and you can [read all about it on the developer center](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/).

(the URL is https://account.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo)

Comment: Thank you Inbar for the info! Very helpful!!